# react-router - server side rendering match

Tags: match, react-router, universal, server-side-rendering

I have this on my server

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    const body = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />)
    res.send(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
            <head>
              <link href="//cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.6.5/css/mui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            </head>
            <body>
              <div id="root">${body}</div>
              <script defer src="assets/app.js"></script>
            </body>
          </html>
          `)
  })
})
```

And this on the client side

```
import { Router, hashHistory, browserHistory, match } from 'react-router'
let history = browserHistory

//client side, will become app.js
match({ routes, location, history }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
  render(<Router {...renderProps} />, document.getElementById('root'))
})
```

**the problem**
It works only when I remove the (let history = browserHistory), but it adds the /#/ hash prefix to my url(which I don't want to happen).

When I leave the let (history = browserHistory) there, it throws an error

*Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
(client) < ! -- react-empty: 1 -
(server) < section data-reactro*

The error message is pretty clear, however, I don't understand why it works with the hashHistory but fails with the browserHistory

Answer (score 0):

version incompatibility issue

**solution**

```
{
  "history": "^2.1.2",
  "react-router": "~2.5.2"
}
```

links:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/3003